# angular filter is not working with special character

Tags: angularjs

Angular filter filter data if user type !@ in search box in order to filter the list.

if i pass !@ as "objectToFilter", then it does not filter the list, it gives me complete list.
$filter("filter")(value, objectToFilter);

can anyone help me.

Comment: Yes, we can. But first please demonstrate error on plunkr or codepen etc..

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/MNytvDk3koRJwZc5C0yc?p=preview

Created the plunker for you example, type !@ in searchbox
But it is not applying the filter as expected.